# How to calculate new value by adding and substracting previous rows in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Have a table of records in which I need a column that will add or substract itself with previous value.

Like this is a source table  order by colun B

| B | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | S |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | A |

From this tabale, I need to add a value of column B with previous value of new colum D if C has A(add)and substract with the value of Colum B with previous value of new colum D if column C has S(substract).

| B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 (0+1) no previous value |
| 2 | S | -1 (1-2) previous value is one |
| 3 | A | 2 (-1+3) previois value is -1 |
| 4 | A | 6 (2+4) previous value is 2 |

Is there any easy way to achieve this in Oracle?

Tried lag() but got the sum or substraction of any two rows only... can not get the self value for addition or substraction.

Comment: Your last example contradicts the rule you said above.  You said, `I need to add a value of column B if C has A(add)`, but in your last example you start with 2 and should add 1 to get 3, instead you get 5???

Comment: And, no lag() just sum().  `Sum(case when C='S' then -B else B end) Over (rows unbounded preceding to current row)`.  But you might want some kind of Order By because there is no intrinsic order to any table.  You must impose it yourself with a sort.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer That is missing an `ORDER BY` clause and will raise an `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` exception.

Comment: For sum() you need a group by clause. Which is not applicable for my purpose. Sum will give final result instead of rowwise result. Edited example to understand my question in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` analytic function with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(CASE c WHEN 'A' THEN +b ELSE -b END) OVER (ORDER BY a) AS d
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (A, B, C) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'A' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: Results sets in SQL (in any dialect, not just Oracle) are non-deterministically ordered (i.e. unordered) unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause and have a column that can be used to specify a deterministic ordering. In this case, you need to have a column (i.e. `A`) that specifies the order so that you can get the rows in a deterministic order.*

Outputs:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | S | -1 |
| 3 | 3 | A | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | A | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UO5fWLHJ)

Comment: I need to add or substract previous value of the new column D with current value of column B on the basis of column C.

Comment: @GovindaThapa In SQL there is no concept of pervious or current unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause and give the rows a deterministic ordering. If you have a column (such as `A`) that allows you to generate a deterministic ordering of the rows then this answer does exactly what you want. If you are not able to generate a deterministic ordering of the rows then your question does not make sense.

Comment: Question edited by adding order by clause also...

Comment: @GovindaThapa As I state in the answer, use the `SUM` analytic function (which is not the same as the `SUM` aggregation function and does not group the results).

Comment: Its working as expexted... thanks for the idea to use sum() analytic function... 